# Javascript menu class toggle

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to make a menu for my website. It's inside div with `display: none` set.

I want my menu to show as clicking on the image. I'm new at JS, so maybe I'm doing it entirely wrong. Are there any right ways to do this?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("menuimg").click(function() {
    $("menu").toggleClass("vis");
  });
});
```

```css
#menu {
  position: fixed;
  display: none;
}

.vis {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header id="mnu">
  <div id="menubackground">
    <img id="menuimg" src="Logo.png" alt="" /></div>
</header>
<header id="menu">
  <div id="hid">
    <img src="Logowhite.png" alt="" />
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: This is just a typo; you're missing the `#` prefix on the id selectors. `$('menu')` should be `$('#menu')` and `$('menuimg')` should be `$('#menuimg')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot the `#` for using id as a selector

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#menuimg").click(function(){
        $("#menu").toggleClass("vis");
    });
});
```

Comment: so it's just a typo